# Input как реализовать after?

Tags: css, input

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в данном inpute  реализовать border-right и данный icon ? Ибо все время проблемы с высотой

Comment: Добавьте ваш вариант реализации, с вашими проблемами. Тогда скажем в чем проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У одиночных элементов из серии `input`, `img` — нет псевдоэлементов `::before` и `::after`

Там есть несколько вариантов, но у меня инпут поставлен внутри дополнительного блока, которому и добавляются стрелочка и бордер на псевдоэлементы.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #dde;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}

.block::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #dde;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dde;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.input {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

body {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input class="input" placeholder="E-mail">
</div>
```

Хотя можно было это дело организовать, поставив маленький квадрат рядом с инпутом. А бордеры такого вида можно рисовать так:

```css
.demo {
  height: 50px; width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<input class="demo">
```